# Using Google Maps, layers of polygons and calculate its intersections

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps, jts-topology-suite, mysql-spatial

I am developing a web application that uses Google Maps and it has polygons (circles and irregular polygons) drawed inside this map.

This polygons are stored into a DataBase (MySQL 5.7) as [Polygons represented by the library JTS](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Polygon.java).

In the web application you can draw a polygon and then, a request is done to a server to check whether ths drawn polygon intersects or not with any other polygon stored in DB.

This process is quite slow and another approach is checking the intersection only in frontend. These is some solutions provided by other mates:

- Using ArcGIS JS. I don't know if in this approach you could use Google Maps or another map is needed.
- Using OpenLayers or Leaflet and maybe ArcGIS JS?
- Using [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) and Google Maps, or maybe, as I mentioned before, OpenLayers or Leaflet?

The problem I have using JTS is that represents circles (specifying radius and center point) is not the same as in Google Maps. So I'm not sure if using JSTS is a good idea.

Comment: Maybe turf.js? Its geospatial manipulation in javascript... http://turfjs.org/